# Creating php file with php

Tags: php, file

I am trying to create php file with php script with php function "fopen" and "fwrite". I am not able to write two things if you can help me with that plz. Here is the script.

```
<?php
$fname='my-name';
$filename = "testme.php";
$ourFileName =$filename;
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w');

$written =  "
esc_html__( 'Try looking in the monthly archives. %1$s', '$fname' );
the_widget( 'Widget_Archives', 'dropdown=1', \"after_title=</h2>$$fname_archive_content\" );

";
fwrite($ourFileHandle,$written);
fclose($ourFileHandle);?>
```

I want to write %1$s as it is which I can't and I also want to write  $fname_archive_content = $my-name_archive_content in line second. Any help plz??
Thanks for looking this question.

Answer (score 1):

[Escape](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) the dollar signs with `\`, and enclose the variable name with curly braces ([complex variable parsing syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)).

```
$written =  "
esc_html__( 'Try looking in the monthly archives. %1\$s', '$fname' );
the_widget( 'Widget_Archives', 'dropdown=1', \"after_title=</h2>\${$fname}_archive_content\" );

";
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I won't panic now. Thanks Don't Panic